# dispatchEvent change on select element cannot be handled by delegate

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following html snippet:-

```
        <fieldset id="container">
            <legend>Event Delegation Test</legend>
            <button type="button" id="btn_select" name="select button">Select</button>
            <input type="text" name="first" autofocus/>
            <input type="text" name="second"/>
            <input type="text" name="third"/>
            <input type="text" name="fourth"/>
            <input type="text" name="fifth"/>
            <select name="Names">
                <option>Tom</option>
                <option>Dick</option>
                <option>Harry</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
```

I have set event delegation on the fieldset (id="container") and added the change event thus:

```
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("change", e => {
let el = e.target,
        name = el.name,
        value = el.value;

console.log("CHANGE element: %s has value %s", name, value);});
```

I have found that using the following code...

```
select.value = "Harry";
select.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

...isn't detected by the delegate handler.

BUT this does work...

```
select.value = "Harry";

let ce = new CustomEvent("change", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: false
});

select.dispatchEvent(ce);
```

WHY?

I have been unable to find any information as to this particular use case peculiarity
Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which browser and version are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to explicitly specify that the event propagates:

`new Event("change", {"bubbles": true});`

The default value for the event propagation (propertie `bubbles`) is false. That is why your delegate handler is not receiving the `change` event.

Comment: f-CJ Doh! What a wally I am. I have just discovered that Event doesn't bubble by default. Nevermind; it works now anyway - thnx.